# Angular2 (Beta 11) throws exception when trying to wrap bootstrap-daterangepicker in component

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, exception, angular, bootstrap-datetimepicker

I am currently evaluating Angular2 (Beta 11). In a prototype I tried to wrap the **bootstrap-daterangepicker** (https://github.com/dangrossman/bootstrap-daterangepicker) in a component.

However I encountered some strange problem which I cannot explain. (It seems the problem occurs only with Beta 10 and 11. I was not able to reproduce the problem with Beta 8 and 9.)

Please have a look on this Plunkr: https://plnkr.co/edit/u958id

The **DateRangePickerComponent** looks like this:

```
import {Component, ElementRef, Inject, OnInit, EventEmitter} from 'angular2/core';

@Component({
    selector: 'date-range-picker',
    template: '<input type="text" class="form-control" />',
})
export class DateRangePickerComponent implements OnInit { 
    elementRef: ElementRef;

    constructor( @Inject(ElementRef) elementRef: ElementRef) {
        this.elementRef = elementRef;
    }

    ngOnInit() {
        var picker : any = jQuery(this.elementRef.nativeElement).find('input')
        picker.daterangepicker();
    }
}
```

Since the **bootstrap-daterangepicker** depends on **Bootstrap/jQuery**, I linked both libraries in the demo and use the **ElementRef** to get a grip on the element for initialization. For simplicity the demo code does not do anything useful with the selected dates.

To reproduce the problem:

1. Start the Plunkr.
2. Open the picker by clicking in the input element.
3. Select a start date followed by the end date.
4. Click on **Apply** to confirm the selection.
5. The picker disappears and the input element shows the selected dates. *So far so good*.
6. Click again on the input element and repeat the date selection.
7. Click again on **Apply**.
8. Now an exception is thrown (`angular2.dev.js:23740`):

`EXCEPTION: Error: Task does not support cancellation, or is already canceled.`

Comment: Issue already tracked [here](https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/7666). Check for @gdi2290 workaround (if you're using webpack). You can see the [website](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/) as well where they added a warning message regarding zone issues in beta.11

Comment: Hi Eric. Thanks for your quick response. I saw the zone issue related message on the Angular2 site, however I did not link it with my problem. I used a clone from webpack (with workaground from @gdi2290) and tried again. Now it seems to work.